# Automating file upload in an Angular site with Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, angular, selenium-webdriver

I need to automate uploading a lot of files, and the site seems to be written with Angular. The upload button uses a hidden input such that it kinda looks like this.

```
<button id="btn4" type="button" class="btn btn-lgrey btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-disabled="showOnlyFiles || hideButtonAddlocal" ng-click="importDocument();">Add Local</button>
<input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" autocomplete="one-time-code" style="display: none;">
```

Used normally I can click the visible button and it'll do all the automatic uploading magic which I assume is what the `ng-click="importDocument();"` thing does.

I have tried the following code:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "fileUpload").send_keys("/path/to/file.pdf")
```

This doesn't seem to do anything in terms of actually uploading the file. When I unhide the hidden input element, it *does* show that a file has been selected, but doesn't go through with the upload process as you would with using the regular button.

The problem is I can't use the regular button, as Selenium as far as I'm aware cannot handle the dialogue box that opens for the OS to input the file path. What are my options here? I can't find a way to run the importDocument() script.

Thanks in advance.