# Changing an Angular $scope function via console

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'll preface by saying I do not work in Angular. I am using Selenium to automate some stuff in an Angular based website as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76211993/5556670) for context.

I've noticed that I can in fact run the aforementioned `importDocument()` function, but that function has a line I would like to omit. So my thought process is to get the function, stringify it, change it, eval it, and put it back where I found it.

In the console I am doing:

```
x = angular.element(document.getElementById('btn4')).scope().importDocument.toString()

angular.element(document.getElementById('btn4')).scope().importDocument = eval("("+x.replace("document.getElementById('fileUpload').click();", "")+")")

angular.element(document.getElementById('btn4')).scope().$apply()
```

and then I would like to run the now changed `angular.element(document.getElementById('btn4')).scope().importDocument()`, however this doesn't work, saying that `$scope is not defined`.

Looking in the sources tab, I see that the original js file is unaffected and instead a VM#### file contains the new evaluated function on its own outside the context of the Angular app.

Would appreciate some help figuring out where to go. Thanks.